# How to use a variable in byte slice in Go

Tags: go

*Probably a big noob question here, so please bear with me.*

To send an HTTP POST request in Go with some body, I can do this:

```
var jsonStr = []byte(`{"someVar":"someValue"}`)
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", APIURL, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
```

However, it seems that I can't use a variable instead of "someValue", like this:

```
someValue := "SomeValue"
var jsonStr = []byte(`{"someVar":someValue}`)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You might want to look into using a map or struct, which can use variables, then marshaling/encoding to JSON instead of typing out the JSON manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because it is a string literal. I suggest trying to serialize your type using [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/).

```
type MyPostBody struct {
    SomeVar string `json:"someVar"`
}

pb := &MyPostBody{SomeVar: "someValue"}
jsonStr, err := json.Marshal(pb)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("could not marshal JSON: %s", err)
}

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", APIURL, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it. To be honest, this feels weird but then again it's all matter of getting used to I guess.

Answer (score 7):

or format the string

```
someValue := "SomeValue"
var jsonStr = []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{"someVar":"%v"}`, someValue))
```

Comment: If someValue string contains " character it will break the JSON.